# De-merits of the application of Laplace's Equation to find electrostatics potentials

Tags: potential, classical-electrodynamics

**QUESTION**: What are the de-merits of the application of Laplace's Equation to find electrostatics potentials?

Our professor told us that the answer was as follows:

> It can be used only when the charge distribution is at the boundaries
>   and not on the region between the boundaries.

But I don't think that it is correct. I think he has just reversed the answer. According to my opinion, the correct answer should be that:

> It can only be used to calculate the electric potential at any point
>   inside the region between the boundary, as specified by the boundary
>   conditions.

Which one is correct?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if there were charge between the boundaries, you would be solving [*Poisson's equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation) rather than Laplace's equation. However, boundary conditions for the potential function are also crucial, because there could always be distant point charges that modify the field in the region of interest, without changing the distribution of charge on the boundary.